# Pandas dataframes concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

|  | SPY | AAPL | IBM | GOOG | XOM | BAC | GLD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-01-10 | 126.72 | 96.59 | 89.56 | 489.46 | 62.47 | 46.40 | 60.59 |
| 2007-01-17 | 128.05 | 94.54 | 90.58 | 497.28 | 63.77 | 46.17 | 62.64 |

| Date | Symbol | Order | Shares |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-01-10 | AAPL | BUY | 2500 |
| 2007-01-17 | AAPL | SELL | 1500 |
| 2007-01-19 | IBM | BUY | 400 |

I am trying to combine these two dataframes into where I can get following result. My first data set has date as index and I tried but couldn't connect with the column name. Please help

| Date | Symbol | Order | Shares | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-01-10 | AAPL | BUY | 2500 | 96.59 |
| 2007-01-17 | AAPL | SELL | 1500 | 94.54 |

Answer (score 1):

You can `.stack()` the first dataframe and then merge it with the second:

```py
tmp = df1.set_index("ID").stack().reset_index(name="Price")
out = df2.merge(
    tmp, left_on=["Date", "Symbol"], right_on=["ID", "level_1"], how="inner"
).drop(columns=["level_1", "ID"])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
         Date Symbol Order  Shares  Price
0  2007-01-10   AAPL   BUY    2500  96.59
1  2007-01-17   AAPL  SELL    1500  94.54
```

---

If dates in your first dataframe are in index, you can try:

```py
tmp = df1.stack().reset_index(name="Price")
out = df2.merge(
    tmp, left_on=["Date", "Symbol"], right_on=["level_0", "level_1"], how="inner"
).drop(columns=["level_0", "level_1"])

print(out)
```

Comment: Thanks bud. But seems like the dataframe1 doesnt have column name for Date. When I set index as ID like you suggested I get this error


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miniconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'ID'

Comment: @MannyBalboa What are the columns in `df1`? Try `print(df1.columns)` If `ID` is index, just do `tmp = df1.stack().reset_index(name="Price")` but adjust column names in merge accordingly.

Comment: When i run print(df1.columns) I get this output

Index(['SPY', 'AAPL', 'IBM', 'GOOG', 'XOM', 'BAC', 'GLD'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

I agree with @Andrej Kesely's suggestion of using `stack` + `reset_index` to perform unpivot and then `merge`.

I prefer to do this with the following code:

```
out = df2.merge(df1.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['Date', 'Symbol', 'Price'], axis=1))
```

out

```
    Date        Symbol  Order   Shares  Price
0   2007-01-17  AAPL    BUY     2500    94.54
1   2007-01-10  AAPL    SELL    1500    96.59
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'SPY': {'2007-01-10': 126.72, '2007-01-17': 128.05}, 
         'AAPL': {'2007-01-10': 96.59, '2007-01-17': 94.54},
         'IBM': {'2007-01-10': 89.56, '2007-01-17': 90.58},
         'GOOG': {'2007-01-10': 489.46, '2007-01-17': 497.28},
         'XOM': {'2007-01-10': 62.47, '2007-01-17': 63.77},
         'BAC': {'2007-01-10': 46.4, '2007-01-17': 46.17},
         'GLD': {'2007-01-10': 60.59, '2007-01-17': 62.64}}

data2 = {'Date': ['2007-01-17', '2007-01-10', '2007-01-19'], 
         'Symbol': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'IBM'], 
         'Order': ['BUY', 'SELL', 'BUY'], 
         'Shares': [2500, 1500, 400]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```